# Установка драйверов Nvidia на ноутбук с debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер, nvidia

Перечитал много форумов, чужих ответов и решил пойти задать свой...

Пытался установить на ноутбук драйвера через apt install nvidia-driver и .run файл

```
Acer nitro 5
Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 mobile
Intel core i5
```

Всё это окончилось для меня печально. Через .run файлы зачастую различные ошибки при установке одна за другой

При установке через apt install nvidia-driver я не прихожу к своей главной цели -- не работает второй монитор и не просто не работает, а xrandr к примеру даже не в курсе, что есть hdmi порт идущий от видюхи...(но прога от зелёных кстати знает, что есть порт и даже какой там моник, но ничего большего как например работающий моник я получить не могу)

Если нужно больше подробностей, то я буду рад их предоставить дабы решить наконец-то эту проблему). И да lspci grep vga выдаёт мне мои 2 видюхи

UPD:
output lspci -vnq:

```
00:00.0 0600: 8086:9b64 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:01.0 0604: 8086:1901 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122, IOMMU group 1
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a0000000-a10fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-0000006201ffffff [size=8224M]
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 0300: 8086:9bc4 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at 6202000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 1180: 8086:1903 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 3
    Memory at 6203100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 0880: 8086:1911
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 4
    Memory at 6203118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 1180: 8086:06f9
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 5
    Memory at 6203117000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 0c03: 8086:06ed (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137, IOMMU group 6
    Memory at a1380000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 0500: 8086:06ef
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 6
    Memory at 6203110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 6203116000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:14.3 0280: 8086:06f0
    Subsystem: 8086:0074
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 7
    Memory at 620310c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 0c80: 8086:06e8
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 8
    Memory at 4010000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 0c80: 8086:06e9
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 8
    Memory at 4010001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 0780: 8086:06e0
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 139, IOMMU group 9
    Memory at 6203113000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 0106: 8086:06d3 (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at a1390000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a1394000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at a1393000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1b.0 0604: 8086:06ac (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123, IOMMU group 11
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: a1200000-a12fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 0604: 8086:06b5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124, IOMMU group 12
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a1100000-a11fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 0601: 8086:068d
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 13

00:1f.3 0403: 8086:06c8 (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 140, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at 6203108000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6203000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 0c05: 8086:06a3
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at 6203112000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 0c80: 8086:06a4
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 0300: 10de:2520 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: 1025:143e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at a0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8G]
    Memory at 6200000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at a1080000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Physical Resizable BAR
    Capabilities: [c1c] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [d00] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [e00] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia

01:00.1 0403: 10de:228e (rev a1)
    Subsystem: 10de:0000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at a1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

06:00.0 0108: 15b7:5009 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: 15b7:5009
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=17 Masked-
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [1b8] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [900] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

07:00.0 0200: 10ec:2600 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: 1025:143d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 15
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Судя по всему у меня сейчас стоит apt install nvidia-driver

UPD2:
output xrandr:

```
vlad@debian:~$ sudo xrandr
[sudo] password for vlad: 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.01    60.02    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27
```

output inxi -Fxz

```
System:    Kernel: 5.10.0-21-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 
           Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Nitro AN515-55 v: V2.01 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: CML model: Stonic_CMS v: V2.01 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: 2.01 date: 01/07/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 43.1 Wh condition: 43.1/57.5 Wh (75%) model: LGC AP18E8M status: Full 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-10300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Comet Lake rev: 2 L2 cache: 8 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 39999 
           Speed: 900 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 3: 900 4: 900 5: 900 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: nvidia v: 525.85.12 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Device-3: Quanta HD User Facing type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus ID: 1-5:3 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.5 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GA106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-21-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: N/A port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           Device-2: Realtek vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: enp7s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus ID: 1-14:4 
           Report: ID: hci0 state: down address: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 20.02 GiB (1.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530 SDBPNPZ-512G-1114 size: 476.94 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WDS100T2B0A-00SM50 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 37 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 91.11 GiB used: 15.55 GiB (17.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 32.3 MiB (33.6%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
           ID-3: /home size: 200.61 GiB used: 4.44 GiB (2.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
           ID-4: /tmp size: 45.53 GiB used: 84 KiB (0.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 59.6 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sda4 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 225 Uptime: 41m Memory: 15.47 GiB used: 2.18 GiB (14.1%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 10.2.1 Packages: 1565 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01
```

Comment: Вы подключили non-free репозиторий? Приложите вывод lspci -vnq после установки nvidia-driver. и lsmod | grep nvidia

Comment: Какой DE используете?

Comment: @Exord, да я подключил non-free и contrib с помощью nano. Использую xfce. Добавил вывод из указанной вами команды

Comment: Какая карта установлена ​​​​в качестве основной в вашей прошивке BIOS / UEFI, Intel или nvidia?

 отправьте журнал xorg, найдите файлы *.conf в папках /etc/X11 и /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d и опубликуйте содержимое, если оно есть.

Comment: Secure boot отключен?

Comment: xrandr вывод приложите пожалуйста. На всякий случай

Comment: inxi -Fxz , ещё было бы не плохо

Comment: @Exord, приложил xrandr & inxi -Fxz. Файлы конфигов отсутствуют, по поводу secure boot он выключен. А вот видеокарта не смог найти там этой инфы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Незнаю почему у меня не получалось ранее, но я смог решить это.
Добавь в sources.list sid, non-free, contrib репозитории, а также отключи безопасную загрузку (secure boot) в uefi/bios чтобы идти дальше

**ОБРАТИ ВНИМАНИЕ, ЧТО ЭТО ДЛЯ НОУТОВ**
Короче знай, если у тебя ноут, то это скорее всего конфигурация optimus и всё что тебе надо познавать ты должен познавать опираясь на это.
Понять что у тебя оптимус можно прописав

```
lspci | grep VGA // для меня это сработало
//на выход ты получишь 2 вывода примерно как у меня
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
// Это и означает, что у тебя Optimus
```

Поняв это я установил и прописал nvidia-detect

```
vlad@debian:~$ nvidia-detect 
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:2520] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 470 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

Угу, моя видюха поддерживает какие-то дефолтные дрова (безпонятия что это такое и где они были изначально). Также поддерживается версия Tesla 470.

Вот на этом моменте я чудесным образом нарыл [эту доку по установке](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) и далее следовал чётко ей, но обязательно обрати внимание на эту строку в доке:
**Читай доку, ибо действия которые описаны в ней, я не описывал тут**

Note: if this lspci command returns more than one line of output, you have an Optimus (hybrid) graphics chipset. After you install the necessary driver package, you'll still need to choose one of the methods on the NVIDIA Optimus page in order to activate and make use of your NVIDIA card.

Тут говорится, что по завершении установки если у тебя оптимус, то перейди по [ссылке](https://wiki.debian.org/NVIDIA%20Optimus) и настрой свой оптимус под свои нужды. Мои действия:
Я выбрал Using NVIDIA PRIME Render Offload т.к. там разные нужны и одна из моих нужд -- использовать 2 моника для работы, для чего вроде как подходит этот метод.

Я ввёл в консоль:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
//не уверен в надобности этих шагов, но у меня они ничего не ломают поэтому упомянул их, ибо реально считаю их нужными
```

Далее нужно замутить конфиг. (Да, на оптимусе тоже его нужно сделать, но многие ресурсы говорят УДАЛИТЕ конфиг с ноутбука. Нет, не удаляйте)

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --prime 

//Если нет такой команды, то сделай её: sudo apt install nvidia-xconfig
```

Сделали это всё и ничего не случилось?

Подруби второй моник и пробуй

```
sudo reboot
```

Не пугайся если у тебя всё запустилось на внешнем монике (у меня было также, ты на верном пути).
Далее в ход идёт команда xrandr

```
vlad@debian:~$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1b8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x1f8 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

Мы должны увидеть Providers: number: 2
Теперь я не уверен, что у всех будет такой же порядок:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource NVIDIA-G0
xrandr --auto
//Вот вообще без понятия, что дала мне эта команда, но изначально мой провайдер видеокарты GeForce 3060 назывался именно NVIDIA-G0 (у тебя name может быть иным, посмотри на это сам и укажи свой)
```

Так окс, а потом по-идее я прописал:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
//modesetting это name моей дискретки
//NVIDIA-0 это name моей Nvidia GeForce 3060 (да, он изменился после первой команды)
```

Ну и на последок теперь каждый мой запуск с двумя мониторами всегда сопровождается этими двумя командами выше и доп. настройками в настройках дисплеев моего xfce (убрать дублирование экранов, выбрать главный, поставить их в правильном порядке)

Я пока не нашёл способ сделать так чтобы мне не приходилось писать это каждый запуск

P.S. Надеюсь я помог тебе, но чтобы решить эту проблему мне я: 5 раз переустановил убитую или замусоренную систему и потратил на это всё около 40-50 часов чтобы разобраться, ибо по чужим ответам я не смог поставить себе. Поэтому пишу данный ответ, ведь новый юзер экспериенс может также помочь другим новичкам с optimus

Comment: Ещё одна заметка с моего полёта: будь готов к тому, что у тебя просто может быть чёрный моник. ЧТо делать? возьми на заметку комбинацию ctrl+alt+f1 (или любая f клавиша) это откроет терминал. Логинишься в своём юзере. После есть другая команда: startx . Эта команда перезагружает X server вроде и у тебя начинает работать визуал. Было также, что всё равно не работает..тогда sudo poweroff в консоль и попробуй ещё. Ещё возможно стоит побаловаться с xrandr в этот момент чтобы оживить, но тут больше опыт работы с этим

Comment: Ещё одна заметка: когда отключен второй моник, то основной моник не даст картинку. Увы не нашёл ничего как: 1. ctrl+alt+f1; 2. логинимся в своего юзера; 3. переходим в root c помощью su root; 4. Идём в cd /etc/X11; 5. переименовываем xorg.conf в другое название чтобы он не нашёлся при загрузке: mv ./xorg.conf ./external-display-xorg.conf; 6. Перезагрузка sudo reboot. Вот такие шаги.

Когда понадобится опять второй моник придётся вернуть обратно название xorg.conf и опять перезагрузиться. Другого решения мной пока не найдено